Potential long-range attack: block not in finalized chain. (when migrating parachain from Rococo to Paeso)
After migration from Rococo to Paseo our chain prepares block but does not suggest them, this error is only found in source on client side, any suggestions how to recover from this?
2024-04-04 21:51:54 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #640830 (0x338b…61e7)
2024-04-04 21:51:54 [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x0fd167da222f10dae826a0433fe4daadcf4a36c2a6bd5c1b085857d5b79030af
2024-04-04 21:51:54 [Parachain]  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (2 ms) [hash: 0x58b2c9517187d90d98ee970c958df0ca274b26672f1679b417765abe85727ddb; parent_hash: 0x0fd1…30af; extrinsics (2): [0x43ae…ac6f, 0x33f9…f0dd]
2024-04-04 21:51:54 [Parachain]  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 1. Hash now 0x05abd6dc9d04acb916efa52e5154ec04db26cf980df8c6075589b06ad96d0261, previously 0x58b2c9517187d90d98ee970c958df0ca274b26672f1679b417765abe85727ddb.
2024-04-04 21:51:54 [Parachain] Block import error: Potential long-range attack: block not in finalized chain.
2024-04-04 21:51:54 [Parachain] err=ClientImport("Potential long-range attack: block not in finalized chain.")

